# In R how to find the first minimum value of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, minimum

How do I find the first minimum value in one column of a dataframe and output a new dataframe with just that row?

For example, for a dataframe named "hospital", for each node, I want to find the minimum time at which "H" is >=1.

| node | time | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |

The result I want to be able to output is:

| node | time | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

One way is to filter your dataframe, and then take the first minimum element for each group:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(H > 0) %>% 
  group_by(node) %>% 
  slice_min(time, n = 1)

   node  time     H
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1
2     2     3     1
3     3     2     2
```